# how to add click event listener in javascript in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

can you please help how to add `click` event listener in `react-project` without using `react - onClick attribute`. I want to use only native javascript.

I tried like this

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
  console.log("====");
  console.log(document.querySelector(".btn"));
  document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener(
    "click",
    function () {
      alert("-----");
    },
    false
  );
});
```

it is not working alert is not showing .can you please help me where i doing wrong.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-shadow-1c4v8?file=/src/App.js:76-340

**I know using `react we can acheive this but I don't want to use reactjs click event` I want to use native javascript and update the state.**

below solution not working when I am using dangerouslyInsertHTML

here is my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-shadow-1c4v8?file=/src/App.js

Comment: The first question is why? If this is born out of some misunderstanding of how part of React works then this might be easily solved and still use the inbuilt handlers. Could you please explain what you are attempting to achieve?

Comment: @JacobSmit sorry for late reply .actually some part of HTML is coming from server so I am using `dangeroulyInsertHTML` .but solution not working https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-shadow-1c4v8?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

you must register event listener in React Hooks

try this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
  const buttonEl = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(counter);
  }, [counter]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const alertFunc = function () {
      alert("-----");
    }
    const buttonRef = buttonEl.current;
    buttonRef.addEventListener(
      "click",
      alertFunc,
      false
    ); 
    // Specify how to clean up after this effect:
    return function cleanup() {
      buttonRef.removeEventListener("click", alertFunc, false)
    };
  })
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <button className="btn" ref={buttonEl}> set countor</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I register listener in hooks, and when the component will unmount I remove the listener

Comment: You should use a ref to get access to the button element and not `document.querySelector`.

Comment: thanks for answering .sorry for late reply.it is not working when I using `dangerously insert HTML` . https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-shadow-1c4v8?file=/src/App.js